# Access managed class member array variable in C++/CLI

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

Since P/Invoke does not support returning dynamic sized arrays (you must statically specify the size of the array at compile time), I decided to write a C++/CLI wrapper for some functions I need in a .net application that is otherwise written in C#.

Take the GetTcpTable2 function from IpHlpApi.dll...
I made C# classes to match the types in that function as follows:

```
public class MibTcpTable2
{
    public int NumEntries;
    public MibTcpRow2[] Table;
}

public class MibTcpRow2
{
    public int State;
    public int LocalAddr;
    public int LocalPort;
    public int RemoteAddr;
    public int RemotePort;
    public int OwningPid;
    public int OffloadState;
}
```

In my C++/CLI program, I call GetTcpTable2 as shown in the MSDN example, and then iterate through the resulting array and assign its output to a new instance of the TcpTable2 class I made in C#.
See code:

```
PMIB_TCPTABLE2 pTcpTable;
ULONG ulSize = 0;
DWORD dwRetVal = 0;

pTcpTable = (MIB_TCPTABLE2 *)MALLOC(sizeof(MIB_TCPTABLE2));
if (pTcpTable == NULL) {
    return nullptr;
}

ulSize = sizeof(MIB_TCPTABLE);
if ((dwRetVal =  ::GetTcpTable2(pTcpTable, &ulSize, TRUE)) == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
{
    FREE(pTcpTable);
    pTcpTable = (MIB_TCPTABLE2 *)MALLOC(ulSize);
    if (pTcpTable == NULL) {
        return nullptr;
    }
}

NetClasses::MibTcpTable2^ managedTable = gcnew NetClasses::MibTcpTable2();
managedTable->Table = gcnew cli::array<NetClasses::MibTcpRow2^>(pTcpTable->dwNumEntries);

if ((dwRetVal = ::GetTcpTable2(pTcpTable, &ulSize, TRUE)) == NO_ERROR)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pTcpTable->dwNumEntries; i++)
    {
        managedTable->Table[i].LocalAddr = pTcpTable->table[i].dwLocalAddr;
        managedTable->Table[i].LocalPort = pTcpTable->table[i].dwLocalPort;
        managedTable->Table[i].OffloadState = pTcpTable->table[i].dwOffloadState;
        managedTable->Table[i].OwningPid = pTcpTable->table[i].dwOwningPid;
        managedTable->Table[i].RemoteAddr = pTcpTable->table[i].dwRemoteAddr;
        managedTable->Table[i].RemotePort = pTcpTable->table[i].dwRemotePort;
        managedTable->Table[i].State = pTcpTable->table[i].dwState;
    }
}
```

However, Visual Studio 2015 hates the accesses to managedTable inside the for loop.  It complains that "expression must have a class type."  Ok, so that usually means you're using the wrong data accessor operator, so I tried a dot instead.  No dice.

How the heck do I access the Table member of managedTable?  The access to it before the for loop was valid. Why isn't it valid inside the for loop?

Comment: You might want to consider using `System.Net.IPEndPoint` instead of two `int`, for each address/port pair

Comment: Not a bad thought. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Be careful to avoid helping too much, the .NET IPGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections()  and GetActiveTcpListeners() methods already do this.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for that. I was unaware of that class. Those two in conjunction with each other are roughly equivalent to GetTcpTable. What I wrote above is equivalent to GetTcpTable2, as it includes the offload state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array access is giving you a handle to a managed object, so shouldn't your field access also be -> rather than . ?

Array[i]->Field

Comment: Wow. Figures that I was completely overlooking the blatantly obvious. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.  Happens to all of us.